# ErrorException Undefined variable $vcont

Tags: php

Estoy necesitando contar cantidad de registros en una collection hasta encontrar el valor no nulo.
Es decir necesito recorrer la tabla para saber cuantos registros pasan hasta encontrar el campo paciente distinto de nulo. Y devolver ese contador.

```
  private function buscalibre($id)
    {
        $turnos = DB::table('turnos')
        ->select('paciente')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->Where('dia','=','2021/03/19')
        ->Where('id','>',$id)
        ->get();

        foreach ($turnos as $t)

         if ($t->paciente=='') {        

              $vcont=$vcont+1;       
         }   

         }

        return $vcont;
           
    }
```

asi como lo escribí me marca error en el return, no me deja ni probarlo.
Como siempre muchas gracias.

Muestro el error al querer guardarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregando la llave

```
 foreach ($turnos as $t) {
            if($t->paciente == null){    
              $vcont=$vcont+1;
              }
            }


        return $vcont;
```

me da el siguiente error al ejecutarlo
ErrorException
Undefined variable $vcont

Comment: Pero no quiero contar cuantos nulos hay, quiero contar cuantos registros hay hasta el valor nulo..
77 nulo
78 nulo
79 'juan'
80 nulo

esto deberia devolverme 2.

si contara nulos me devolveria 3

Comment: ahi edite poniendo la llave y el error es en la ejecucion

Comment: aca $vcont=$vcont+1;

Comment: Tenes razón no me di cuenta la pucha... listo y para que termine el ciclo al encontrar uno no nulo le puse un   break
MIL GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

Al final era que la variable no tenía valor alguno asignado, entonces al declararla

```
$vcont=0;
```

Quedó resuelto. Ademas agregue el break para salir del ciclo al encontrar el primer valor no nulo.